# How to fix 'model code generator' in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I modelling a simple library management system that able to register user and the user can issue a book.

I want the asp.net IdentityUser to create one -to many relationShip with BookIssue Custom table. because I am new to asp.net mvc 5, I can not fix the problem please help me.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public virtual ICollection<BookIssue> BookIssues { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BookIssue> BookIssues { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Catagory> Catagories { get; set; }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BookIssue>()
        .HasRequired(n => n.ApplicationUser)
        .WithMany(a => a.BookIssues)
        .HasForeignKey(n => n.ApplicationUserId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }
}
```

BookIssue Model:

```
public int BookIssueId { get; set; }       
public int BookId { get; set; }
public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }       
public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set;
```

The generated error:

> There was an error running the selected code generator. 'Unable to
>   retrieve metadata for Librart.Models.BookIssuee'.One or more
>   validation errors were detected during model generation:
>   Library.Models.IdentityUserLogin: EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no
>   key defined.Define the key for this EntityType.
>   Library.Models.IdentityUserRole: EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no
>   key defined.Define the key for this EntityType.

And many other errors are generated.